# Communicate between docker containers is not working [Spring Boot]

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I'm very new to Docker. I'm building a Spring Boot project using Docker. I have 3 containers running and they need to communicate to each other. I already set up the network and call another container by using a service name but it's not working.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:

  payment_service:
    container_name: payment_service
    image: code/platform-service
    build:
      context: payment-api/
    ports:
      - "3001:8000"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - /home/ubuntu/logs/payment_service:/opt/app/logs
    networks:
      - api_network

  partner_service:
    container_name: partner_service
    image: code/partner-service
    build:
      context: partner-api/
    ports:
      - "3002:8000"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - /home/ubuntu/logs/partner_service:/opt/app/logs
    networks:
      - api_network

  cms_service:
    container_name: cms_service
    image: code/cms-service
    build:
      context: cms-api/
    ports:
      - "3003:8000"
    restart: always  
    volumes: 
      - /home/ubuntu/logs/cms_service:/opt/app/logs
    networks:
      - api_network

networks:
  api_network:
    driver: bridge
```

And here is my docker network ls,

```
NETWORK ID     NAME               DRIVER    SCOPE
ad84ee5aa4e9   bridge             bridge    local
571e44f11ff2   code_api_network   bridge    local
990739bf2bbe   host               host      local
45f55f4b62aa   none               null      local
```

Below is my network inspector,

```
{
    "Name": "code_api_network",
    "Id": "571e44f11ff23c49b6085eb79ab649839663bf5d66c3cf189df87badbd5b8ed8",
    "Created": "2021-06-24T16:38:18.462179716Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.26.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.26.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "5e24b7a17678319f6e7f427f6b0550a5062444859fca551f394bf1f7e272a9de": {
            "Name": "cms_service",
            "EndpointID": "2331c2c8226e76ca79fffd9ad7ae3dfacb679881973bca6a0d7ab908a8a31e7c",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "8b83090efc74640a731bb27ecae66abef4aceb0093aac3197d1e9e920569c3a6": {
            "Name": "payment_service",
            "EndpointID": "9a6235ea3dad03b3c74262ed2d072e6a402282e4fd8ed02d5516e8e8f115ca28",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "a21dc91defb8eeb6d68ac792736b0836ab2a6993cde5d86c85442be1c51c2333": {
            "Name": "partner_service",
            "EndpointID": "bbbf7fccf66cdaa43bcbba0c3c65522da726a2ad0c60b4560bce11885cab607c",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "api_network",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "code",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.21.2"
    },
    "CreatedTime": 1624552698462
}
```

When I want the **payment_service** connect to **partner_serivce** I always get connection refused error like this

```
I/O error on POST request for "http://partner_service/api/v1/users/authen/refresh_token": Connection refused (Connection refused);
```

I also tried to add port 3002 like http://partner_serivce:3002 but it's still not working. Do I miss anything ? Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the service is listening on port 8000, that needs to be included in the URL.  (`ports:` aren't used or required for inter-container communication; the default HTTP port is 80.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks a lot. It's seem nothing but you've just saved my day!  What I found more is about naming. I should not use "_" on my network name.

Comment: Compose [provides a `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and in most cases I'd recommend just using that; delete all of the `networks:` blocks from the file.  You also don't need to manually specify `container_name:`.